# min & sum of discrete stopping times using alternate definition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Let $A, B$ be stopping times of a process $X_0, ... X_n$ where $A$ is a stopping time iff $I_{A = k}$ is a function of $X_0, ... X_k$ (where $I$ denotes an indicator variable).

We want to show that:

1. $min(A, B)$ is a stopping time.

In other words, I guess we want to show that $I_{min(A, B) = k}$ is a function of $X_0, ... X_k$ given that both $I_{A = k}$ and $I_{B = k}$ are. This might sound like a dumb question, but I am struggling to express $I_{min(A, B) = k}$ in terms of $I_{A = k}$ and $I_{B = k}$. Since $min(A, B)$ is either $A$ or $B$, it seems that $I_{min(A, B) = k}$ is either 
$I_{A = k}$ or $I_{B = k}$, both of which are functions of $X_0, ... X_k$. I am confused on where to go from here or if what I just pointed is even relevant. Can we do something in terms of set unions of the process $X_0, ... X_k$?

2. $A + B$ is a stopping time.
   Again, we want to show that $I_{A + B = k}$ is a function of $X_0, ... X_k$. I am having the same difficulty as above.

(Please no measure-theoretic results or proofs as I am not familiar with measure theory! I am supposed to work with this definition only.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are stopping times, so $I_{A=k}$ and $I_{B=k}$ are both determined by $X_0,...X_k$ (this is simply the definition). For the first part it would be convenient to use that also $I_{A>k}$ is solely determined by $X_0,...X_k$:
$$I_{\min\{A,B\}>k}=I_{A>k}I_{B>k},$$
So the minimum of the two is termined by $X_0,...X_k$ and hence it is a stopping time.

The second part is just a matter of summing over all the possibilities:
$$I_{A+B=k}=\sum_{n=0}^k I_{A=n}I_{B=k-n}.$$

You should be able to conclude the argumentation now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what is happening in the first part -- why are we interested in the indicator of $min(A, B) > k$? I guess I'm a little lost as to how it relates to $min(A, B)  = k$. In particular, how do you get from $I_{\min\{A,B\}>k}=I_{A>k}I_{B>k}$ to concluding that the minimum of the two is determined by $X_0, ... X_k$?

Comment: Notation wise, it is easier to show that $\min(A,B)>k$ is a stopping time than $\min(A,B)=k.$ Using that $I_{A>k}=1-\sum_{n=0}^k I_{A=n}$ and $I_{C=k}=I_{C>k}-I_{C\leq k-1}$ you can also derive an expression for the minimum of two stopping times. Now each of those indicator functions in the summation are functions of solely the random variables $X_0,...,X_n$ and hence you find an expression that in total only depends on $X_0,...,X_n$. I hope this helps.

Comment: yes, it does! I see now, thank you very much for clarifing! @userunknown